# My Mac is making an odd noise every couple of minutes

Tags: macos, audio

Total Mac OS noob here, after spending a lifetime on Windows I have my first Mac.

Every couple minutes I hear an odd sound (playing through the speakers), it sounds like two beeps in quick succession, with a puddle-like noise in the background.

It doesn't seem to be anything listed under Sound Effects in the control panel.

What does this sound mean, and do I have to do anything?

Comment: What happens if you adjust the volume? Does the volume of the sound change too?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Yes it does

Comment: Could you record the sound for us? For example using the voice memo app on your phone.

Comment: I'll try my best

Comment: Found it by cycling through the sounds on various apps, it was the *Contact Available* sound on Skype, never heard that on Windows, cheers

Comment: @JMK Then answer your own question, its allowed, and you even get a badge from it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the sound Skype makes for a Contact Available notification.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution

Go to Skype-> Preferences -> notifications-> Event: Contact becomes available and untick "play sound"

I'm almost 100% sure that I don't have  any pending request yet this sound plays randomly in every minute. I removed the tick from the menu and it's fine now.